# Protect files + svn command

Tags: security, root, zend-guard

I have a project that is based in the UK(Servers)
The project will be duplicated to Spanish servers
The root access will be given to Spanish admins.

The main idea is to protect project files from read and execute the commands for Spanish admins.(We have a reason why we need  it)

- Protect files to view a code and execution
- Protect the execution of svn commands

My thoughts are:

1.Using Zend Guard or ioncube(that will allow you to steal the code.)

- Can be used for a code encryption.(But it can be easily
  decrypted)

2.Limited root access

- Can be set up for the project folder + svn commands.

Any advice and suggestions with links are welcome.